# AWS Lambda Java Application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I come from a Java background and now I am getting started with AWS. It seems to me that, although it is possible to write Lambda Functions in Java, appararently, it is not possible to write Lambda Applications in Java since only NodeJS is available as runtime for a Lambda Application. Is that correct? I created a NodeJs lambda application and it's so nice to have the CodeCommit and continuous delivery out of the box once the application is built and I was kindof wishing for the same integration but with my application written in Java.

Comment: [Getting Started with Amazon Corretto 8 on Docker Images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/docker-install.html), [Deploy Docker Containers
on Amazon Elastic Container Service (Amazon ECS)](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/deploy-docker-containers/).

Comment: An AWS Lambda function can run for a maximum of 15 minutes. It is ideal for microservices and small tasks, but not for traditional applications. Many people have, however, created _serverless applications_ that use AWS Lambda functions and require no application server. See: [What Is the AWS Serverless Application Model (AWS SAM)?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html)

Comment: What's the difference between Lambda Function and Lambda Application? [Lambda runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) include Java, node.js, Python, Ruby, Go, and even .NET.

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984174/how-to-create-a-codepipeline-to-build-jar-file-from-java-code-stored-at-github-a

Comment: @kichik If you go to AWS Console -> Lambda, in the left side you will have Applications and Functions. Functions seem to provide the flexibility of writing them in any of those languages you rightly said. Applications on the other hand seem to me as a "way" of organizing Lambda functions (and I find this organization nice). However this Applications seem to be available only for NodeJS runtime.